# How secure is using a URL path as a key to authenticate a update to a sinatra-based webapp?

Tags: security, rest, sinatra, url-routing

So this app I'm making needs to be able to update it's content and this is what I'm thinking

```
#myapp.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    #display some content
    ... 
end

get '/YE0ASD89A09DF8DS0JALS' do  #some randomly generated path only I know to access
    #updates some content
    ... 
end
```

So whenever I accessed myapp.com/YE0ASD89A09DF8DS0JALS it'd be like authenticating my admin status without the whole rigamarole of passwords, security tokens and such and then some changes would occur within the app.

I guess my question is, how visible is the routing structure of a sinatra based app from outside? e.g. would other people / robots be aware of the path to access it without knowing it's there through crawling or whatever?  Would this work how I envision it?.................. or is it just a stupid idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting solution, this would be an example of Security by obscurity and your app could be exposed to internal Man in the middle attacks in case someones get access into your server, or also it COULD be disclosed by some log inclusion or file bruteforcing (using dirbuster bruteforcer as example). It's highly unlikely that someone finds out that path but possible.

And of course if somehow that strange links are showed in some part of your webapp it will be noted by spiders or attackers.

You should protect your methods, authenticate and authorize the access to your administrative scripts. Security by obscurity it's not a good security practice.

Comment: Lol thanks for the response and making it seem like I'm making something big and important, but really the obscure path would be just to like manually validate there was an update to the database and send a push notification to iphone apps telling them to get the new content.  It's nothing network damaging or creating information risks, and I'd rather have it as simple for the client I'm making the thing for to use as possible... sending them a link seemed the simplest way haha.  I agree with you about the poor practice and will accept, but do you think it would work for my purposes?